# how to create a macro using this process flowchart?

Tags: vba

Can you please help me get the vba code to highlight the minimum and maximum value of this column?

Ex:

```
   Col A   | Col B
   --------+---------
   Store 1 |   500
   Store 2 |   400
   Store 3 |   300
   ========+=========
   Total   |  1200
```

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) Actually, you don't need VBA for this - conditional formatting using MIN & MAX will do the job smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree  @Peter L comment that conditional formatting using MIN & MAX will do the job smoothly, 
But if you really want VBA code, this approach could do the job

```
Sub HighlightMinMax()
 Const column As Integer = 2
 Dim row As Integer, minRow As Integer, maxRow As Integer
 Dim minValue, maxValue
 ' initialize variables
 row = 1
 minRow = 1
 maxRow = 1
 minValue = Cells(row, column)
 maxValue = Cells(row, column)
 ' loop until found "Total" in the first column
 While Cells(row, 1) <> "Total"
    Debug.Print Cells(row, 1) ' inspect the label
    If (Cells(row, column) < minValue) Then
        minRow = row
        minValue = Cells(row, column)
    End If
    If (Cells(row, column) > maxValue) Then
        maxRow = row
        maxValue = Cells(row, column)
    End If
    row = row + 1
 Wend
 ' select the cell with the min value and highlight it ...changing the background color to green
 Cells(minRow, column).Select
 With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
 End With
 ' select the cell with the max value and highlight it ...changing the background color to red
 Cells(minRow, column).Select
 With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
 End With
 Cells(maxRow, column).Select
 With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
 End With
End Sub
```